# Emacs Mode For Editing Guitar/Bass Tablature?

Tags: major-mode

I have been looking for a while, and have not been able to find an Emacs major mode for editing Guitar/Bass tablature.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think [Lilypond](https://lilypond.org/) can do tablature and there is a lilypond mode to help enter music (although I have no idea how well it works for tablature - it's ok for standard music notation). There is also an ob-lilypond evaluator for use with Org mode's Babel system, but again, I have no idea how well it would work for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same, found this gem in my searches. This post is long gone and dead. But it's for posterity, since people who search the same thing will most likely stumble upon your question. If you were still looking well now you have an answer.

In all cases enjoy tablature-mode

https://gist.github.com/mjkramer/171ff6af9c66404a81e38d2015848903

Comment: Please summarize the content found at that link. Otherwise, this is a link-only answer and so should be deleted. Thx.